# Carry out az login inside PowerShell task

Tags: azure-devops, azure-functions

We have a Powershell script that loops over a number of JSON config items and stops our Azure function apps using the Stop-AzureRmWebApp cmdlet.

What we want to do now is deploy functions as well from our zip files already built using az functionapp deployment cli. However,we get an error saying that we need to login first e.g az login.

How can we call az login without using a plain text username or password? Our service principal has already logged in implicitly when the PowerShell runs so is there any way of accessing a token or similar in our PowerShell to achieve this?

Comment: Do you use Hosted agent or Private agent?

Answer (score 3):

When using Username and Password or using SP's identity and secret, there are two options you could get around.

First would be to use the suggestion from @Shayki, use the Variables as a "secret". 
[image: Setting a secret Variable in the Pipeline]
Using this is like a hash, once you lock it, you will only be able to replace it and not get the value back. So it is pretty secure.

Second option is to use a KeyVault, this would be the best option, as this is secured using Azure AD and also could easily be updated and or retrieved (with right credentials). Here are the simple steps.

1. Create a KeyVault in Azure, and store the Service Principal's access key/secret as a "secret" - [MS Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/quick-create-portal) is a good start for this.
2. Create a new step on the Azure Devops Pipeline called the "Azure Key vault"
   [image: Azure Key Vault Step]
3. Fill in the details, like the Azure Subscription and the Key Vault name (this is the name of the Key Vault from Step 1).
4. Pay attention to the secret filter, if you have more than one secret stored in the key vault using a "*" will bring out all the secrets. So I would recommend use the ones you need. You can also provide a comma separated list of secrets. 
   [image: Key vault Steps]
5. When the secrets are downloaded you will be able to use them like any other Variable in your pipeline i.e. $secretname

Hope the steps are explanatory enough for you to make a choice, let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: This is the method we used in the end successfully.

Answer (score 0):

You can store the username and password as a variables and do them secret (near the variable select the lock icon), now the variables will be encrypted and not plan text.

**P.S** - You can do it only in the designer and not in the `.yaml` pipeline.